# how to solve asynchronous behaviour in search Box react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

so im trying to implement a search box with useState and useEffect. we have an array of objects and want to filter it according to our search term. here is my implementation:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const array = [
    { key: '1', type: 'planet', value: 'Tatooine' },
    { key: '2', type: 'planet', value: 'Alderaan' },
    { key: '3', type: 'starship', value: 'Death Star' },
    { key: '4', type: 'starship', value: 'CR90 corvette' },
    { key: '5', type: 'starship', value: 'Star Destroyer' },
    { key: '6', type: 'person', value: 'Luke Skywalker' },
    { key: '7', type: 'person', value: 'Darth Vader' },
    { key: '8', type: 'person', value: 'Leia Organa' },
];

let available = []


const Setup = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState('');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        available = array.filter(a => a.value.startsWith(state));
    },[state])

    const show = state ? available : array;

    return <>
        <input value={state} onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)} type="text" className="form"/>
        {show.map(a => {
            return <Data id={a.key} key={parseInt(a.key)} value={a.value} type={a.type}/>
        })}
    </>
}

const Data = (props) => {
    return <>
    <div>
        <p>{props.value}</p>
    </div>

    </>
}



export default Setup;
```

the problem starts when we give our search box a valid search term(like 'T'). i expect it to change the output accordingly(to only show 'Tatooine') but the output does not change.
meantime if you add another character to search term(like 'a' which would set our search term to 'Ta') it will output the expected result. in the other words, search term is not applied synchronously. do you have any idea why is that

Comment: your question is not clear, do you have a JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook is triggered when the component mounts, rerenders or unmounts. In your case, the change of the search field causes a rerender because of the change of the `state`. This results in your `useEffect` triggering *after* the state change and is too late for what you need.

If you type "Ta" into your field, you'll see it works, but it appears as if the search is one step behind.

You can simply remove the use of `useEffect` and filter when you render. This means you can also remove the whole logic around the `available` and `show` variables:

```
const Setup = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={state}
        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        className="form"
      />
      {array
        .filter((a) => a.value.startsWith(state))
        .map((a) => (
          <Data
            id={a.key}
            key={parseInt(a.key, 10)}
            value={a.value}
            type={a.type}
          />
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

There is some good information in the [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)  docs.

Answer (score 1):

You just add toLowerCase mehtod to your filter function. just like this :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const array = [
  { key: "1", type: "planet", value: "Tatooine" },
  { key: "2", type: "planet", value: "Alderaan" },
  { key: "3", type: "starship", value: "Death Star" },
  { key: "4", type: "starship", value: "CR90 corvette" },
  { key: "5", type: "starship", value: "Star Destroyer" },
  { key: "6", type: "person", value: "Luke Skywalker" },
  { key: "7", type: "person", value: "Darth Vader" },
  { key: "8", type: "person", value: "Leia Organa" }
];

let available = [];

const Setup = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    available = array.filter((a) => a.value.toLowerCase().startsWith(state));
  }, [state]);

  const show = state ? available : array;

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={state}
        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        className="form"
      />
      {show.map((a) => {
        return (
          <Data
            id={a.key}
            key={parseInt(a.key)}
            value={a.value}
            type={a.type}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

const Data = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>{props.value}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Setup;
```

and here is the working example : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-meninsky-6jder?file=/src/App.js:0-1269)

Comment: thanks for your comment but it aint working in your code too, the problem is not about letter cases its about asynchronous behaviour

Comment: Agreed, not the answer.

Comment: The example doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just pull out useEffect.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const array = [
    { key: '1', type: 'planet', value: 'Tatooine' },
    { key: '2', type: 'planet', value: 'Alderaan' },
    { key: '3', type: 'starship', value: 'Death Star' },
    { key: '4', type: 'starship', value: 'CR90 corvette' },
    { key: '5', type: 'starship', value: 'Star Destroyer' },
    { key: '6', type: 'person', value: 'Luke Skywalker' },
    { key: '7', type: 'person', value: 'Darth Vader' },
    { key: '8', type: 'person', value: 'Leia Organa' },
];

let available = [];

const Setup = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState('');

    available = array.filter(a => a.value.startsWith(state));

    const show = state ? available : array;

    return (
        <>
            <input
                value={state}
                onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}
                type='text'
                className='form'
            />
            {show.map(a => {
                return (
                    <Data
                        id={a.key}
                        key={parseInt(a.key)}
                        value={a.value}
                        type={a.type}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};

const Data = props => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <p>{props.value}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Setup;
```

Comment: thanks for the comment and your solution; could you tell me why useEffect is causing trouble in this case?

Comment: useEffect is executed when the component mounts, rerenders or unmounts. In your case, the change of the search field causes a rerender because of the change of state. This means your useEffect is executing after the state change and is too late. If you type "Ta" into the field, you'll see it works, but it's one step behind. Edit: I'll post an answer with this + links.

Answer (score 1):

This must solve it

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    const array = [
      { key: "1", type: "planet", value: "Tatooine" },
      { key: "2", type: "planet", value: "Alderaan" },
      { key: "3", type: "starship", value: "Death Star" },
      { key: "4", type: "starship", value: "CR90 corvette" },
      { key: "5", type: "starship", value: "Star Destroyer" },
      { key: "6", type: "person", value: "Luke Skywalker" },
      { key: "7", type: "person", value: "Darth Vader" },
      { key: "8", type: "person", value: "Leia Organa" }
    ];
    
    const Setup = () => {
      const [state, setState] = useState("");
      const [available, setAvailable] = useState(array);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setAvailable(array.filter((a) => a.value.startsWith(state)));
      }, [state]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <input
            value={state}
            onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            className="form"
          />
          {available.map((a) => {
            return (
              <Data
                id={a.key}
                key={parseInt(a.key)}
                value={a.value}
                type={a.type}
              />
            );
          })}
        </>
      );
    };
    
    const Data = (props) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <p>{props.value}</p>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Setup;
```